# My AJAX call won't work on next page untill I hit refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My javascript/ajax works on my page at 'http://localhost:3000/' but when I click next page and it goes to page 'http://localhost:3000/?page=2' it does not work until I hit the refresh button and then it will work.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

edit* i attached the haml call for the next page.

```js
    $(function() {
        $('.show_event').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log("click")
            $.get(this.href,function (code){
                var divs = $(code).filter(function(){
                    return $(this).is('name')
                });
                divs.each(function() {
                    $('.event-text').replaceWith('<div class="event-text">' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
= link_to 'Next page', page: @pages[:page] + 1 unless @pages[:page] >= @pages[:last_page]
```

Comment: define `next page`. Is it an ajax page within this page? Or a new server page?

Comment: It's a new server page.

Comment: Not enough known. Are any errors thrown in console? What is navigation flow to next page? Have you cleared browser cache?

Comment: No errors in console, cleared cache.  I attached the Haml call to the next page.  Is that what you are looking for by 'navigation flow'? Any clues of where I could check?  Only after I refresh and it says 'Navigated to ....' in console does it work.

Comment: A friend of mine said its a problem with turbolinks in rails.

Comment: not even clear what `isn't working`. Are all the scripts being included?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am working on a solution as well.  Everything works as planned when a new page is from the server but when I click next page the scripts are not loading until I hit refresh they load. My friend says the problem has something to do with turbolinks.

Comment: If that's the case and scripts aren't laoding this whole question should just be deleted. Most likely a common issue whatever turbolinks does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem.  Turbolinks was doing funky stuff.

```js
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
function ready() {
    $( function () {
        $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.show_event', function ( evt ) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log( "click" )
            $.get( this.href, function ( code ) {
                var divs = $( code ).filter( function () {
                    return $( this ).is( 'div#event' )
                } );
                divs.each( function () {
                    $( '.event-text' ).replaceWith( '<div class="event-text">' + $( this ).html() + '</div>' );
                } );
            } );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.show_event', function(evt) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Your code works but I still have the same problem.  Only after I refresh the next page it will make the AJAX call.  Let me know if it the problem could be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Did you look in browser's console? Are there any errors before the reload?

Comment: no errors but I'm guessing its how I call the next page.  I am not getting the usual 'Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?page=2' that i get when I go to a new page.

Comment: A friend of mine said it is a problem with turbolinks in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are loading page 2 into page 1, and then expecting the link to be clicked and the action repeated.

The problem is that the new html being loaded hasn't been bound with the event handling.

You can use a delegate, similar to the following

```
 $(document).delegate(".show-event", "click", function () { /* code here */ });
```